# Django and Timezones: how to render aware datetime as a naive one in template (with pytz)

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz

I have those models:

```
class TimeZone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40, unique = True, editable = False)
    def tz(self):
        return pytz.timezone(str(self.name))

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    timezone = models.ForeignKey(TimeZone)

class PlaceAction(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name='Stop place')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        place_tz = self.place.timezone.tz()
        if self.action_time:
            self.action_time = place_tz.localize(self.action_time)
        return super(PlaceAction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My users enter a place and a naive datetime in the form.
I have the timezone of the place in DB already, so I do not require a timezone from my users. I convert and save this datetime as an aware datetime in DB (I use Postgres).
The data saves correctly with the correct offset.

When I want to render the data (in an update form for example), Django converts it back to a naive datetime, but uses the settings.py's default timezone (TIME_ZONE = 'UTC').
I would like to know the best way to convert back the aware datetime to a naive one, using the correct timezone (the one of the Place object). I would rather have the conversion at the model level instead of the template level (I use JQueryUI for the datetime picking, and since the first conversion is done there, I would rather have the reverse conversion at the same place).

A few of my ideas:
In the model PlaceAction **init**()?
With a custom manager?

I could not find a best practice in the docs for the reverse conversion to a different timezone than the default one. Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method to `PlaceAction` that converts to naive then use that in your template.

```
class PlaceAction(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name='Stop place')

    def naive_action_time (self):
        """action_time but without the timezone :-)

        """
        # Updated from Renaud Milon's comment
        return self.action_time.astimezone(place_tz).replace(tzinfo=None)
```

.

```
{% place_action.naive_action_time %}
```

Comment: Apparently, there is a queryset method for that in development. [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#datetimes)

Comment: And to get the correct time in the original timezone: `self.action_time.astimezone(place_tz).replace(tzinfo=None)`

Comment: Ah yes of course, `astimezone` should cover off DLS.  Additioanlly you might be interested in https://github.com/mfogel/django-timezone-field for your timezone field.  It validates against ptyz and returns a ptyz.Timezone() object as well.

Answer (score 0):

A naive datetime is a datetime that doesn't know about timezones. To render a timezone aware datetime as if it was naive, you simply do not display the timezone.

> "I would like to know the best way to convert back the aware datetime
>   to a naive one, using the correct timezone"

That sentence simply doesn't make any sense. With naive datetimes, there is no correct timezone. I suspect that what you want is to convert the date to a specific timezone, from the UTC datetime the database gives you.

And the correct place to do that is in the view. Keep to UTC internally at all times, and convert only for display. That's the simples way.

Comment: Yes, but HOW do you convert it for display?

Comment: datetime.strftime() usually.